# Like button dialog cropping due to introduced span with element style width of 75px

Tags: html, facebook-like

I'm having a problem with the like button which seems to be cropping the pop-out dialog like so

[image: Cropped Facebook Like dialog]

My markup is this

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<%= campaign_link(share_link, campaign, :facebook)%>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

It seems to be because of a `span` element with an element style width of 75px being introduced.

```
<div class="fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" data-href="http://app.bunch.dev/clubs/brc/posts/50564b4281772e72d1000007?utm_campaign=share_discussion&amp;utm_medium=facebook&amp;utm_source=bunchcc" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false">
  <span style="height: 20px; width: 75px; ">
    <iframe id="f1447ba434" name="f3f4b5ff04"...
```

Would welcome any thoughts on why this is happening and how I can prevent/work around it.

Comment: This probably has something to do with the markup on your page. A link would be useful.

Comment: Llink is here http://app.bunch.cc/rides/506e7344ccba560002000096 Like button is at bottom of left hand column. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get any way to solve it? Cause I'm stuck with the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but in case it helps someone: it probably has to do with a `max-width: 100%` or `width: 100%` rule on iframes. I had the exact same issue and solved it with:

```
.fb-like iframe{
    max-width: none;
}
```